# Cannot call method getPosition in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to use method getPosition in this code :

```
alert("Tap location in this map");
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    mArray[count] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });
});
mArray[count].getPosition();
```

But I cannot call getPosition.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPosition' of undefined
```

`count` is a global variable.

```
var count=0;
var mArray = [];
```

Can someone explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your question has it, mArray[count].getPosition()  executes before the click event runs (but after it has been defined), that code doesn't execute until the 'click' happens.  This should work (but not sure why you would want to do it this way):

```
alert("Tap location in this map");
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    mArray[count] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });
    mArray[count].getPosition();
});
```